# What's the difference between abort() and exit() in Node?

Tags: node.js

I noticed that both `process.exit()` and `process.abort()` both stop a script. What are the differences between the two besides that one logs `Aborted`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`process.abort()` stops the process immediately.

`process.exit([exitCode])` method instructs Node.js to terminate the process **as quickly as possible**. You can also specify an **exit code**.

For exit codes:

- `0` means the process was exited successfully.
- `1` means it ended abnormally.
- When omitted, `0` is the default value.

Comment: what does 'as quickly as possible' mean?
what's different between this mode and 'immediately'?

Comment: @BeenoTung I have found that it's possible for some code to prevent the exiting when process.exit() is called. In those cases I needed to call process.abort(). I'm still trying to figure out exactly what can block process.exit(). I know it's certain things in the active-requests queue but I don't know what...

Answer (score 7):

Calling `process.exit()` will force the process to exit as quickly as possible even if there are still asynchronous operations pending that have not yet completed fully, including I/O operations to process.stdout and process.stderr.

The proper recommended way to exit from process is to set the exit code and allow process to exit naturally because calling `process.exit()` forces the process to exit before any additional writes to stdout can be performed.

```
process.exitCode = 1;
```

If it is necessary to terminate the Node.js process due to an error condition, throwing an uncaught error and allowing the process to terminate accordingly is safer than calling process.exit().

The `process.abort()` method causes the Node.js process to exit **immediately** and generate a core file.

Answer (score 5):

The [process.exit()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) method instructs Node.js to terminate the process as quickly as possible with the specified exit code.

If the code is `0` mean exists as success case.

if the code is `1` mean exists as failer case.

And

The [process.abort()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_abort) method causes the Node.js process to exit immediately and generate a core file.

Nothing more difference I have seen except those

Answer (score 5):

`abort` - this results in the abnormal  termination  of the process.

`exit`  - function causes normal process termination