# Aborting a process in node.js

Tags: node.js

What does following stack trace mean when I call `process.abort()`?

```
Error: Command failed: node test/abort.js
 1: 0x1000621d5 node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0x1000b8125 node::Chdir(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0x1004880d2 v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(v8::internal::CallHandlerInfo*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0x1001d89ec v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0x1001d8218 v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0xcae5e24fc7d
```

Is it possible to abort process without error?

Answer (score 3):

You’d generally want to do a `process.exit(0)` and let the program terminate itself. `process.abort` aborts immediately. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39946502/whats-the-difference-between-abort-and-exit-in-node) SO thread for details of `exit` vs `abort`