# How to generate core dump of an exiting node process with gdb?

Tags: node.js, gdb, coredump

I have an issue in my nodejs process when it runs out of memory for a certain flow.
So I'd like to generate a core-dump to investigate the issue.

This is a very concise version of my app just to show the issue and have some code snippet:

```
const spawnProcess = require('spawn-process');
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // Lets say I want to generate a core-dump here:
   async () => {
      await spawnProcess('gdb', ['generate-core-file'], {
          stdio: [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr],
      }).then((res) => {
          console.log("gdb process: then");
      }).catch((err) => {
          console.log("gdb process: error");
          console.log(err);
      });
  })();

  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

I'm actually not sure which command to run for gdb process. And if such a command exists that it can generate a core dump to a this nodejs process which is a parent process in this case.

I get the following error:

```
gcc: error: generate-core-file: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
gdb process: error
Error
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/draft/node_modules/spawn-process/build/es5/index.cjs:65:18)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
    at Process.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:131:17)
```

Someone knows if it is possible to create a core-dump of an exiting node.js I'm runing inside?

The bigger context is that this node.js is running inside a container and I don't want to use kernel or sys commands to generate the core-dump

Comment: Why gcc error in error message? Did you mean `gdb` in `spawnProcess()` arguments, but actually supplied `gcc` by mistake?

Comment: Why not to use `process.abort()` instead of running gdb? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/39946502/72178.